# Azure Key Vault not retrieving ClientId or ClientSecret from App Settings

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to use Azure Key Vault from within my ASP.NET MVC Web Application, and I am following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application).

My Web.config looks like this (same as in the instructions):

```
<!-- ClientId and ClientSecret refer to the web application registration with Azure Active Directory -->
<add key="ClientId" value="clientid" />
<add key="ClientSecret" value="clientsecret" />

<!-- SecretUri is the URI for the secret in Azure Key Vault -->
<add key="SecretUri" value="secreturi" />
```

And my method to obtain the access token looks like this (same as instructions):

```
//add these using statements
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Configuration;

//this is an optional property to hold the secret after it is retrieved
public static string EncryptSecret { get; set; }

//the method that will be provided to the KeyVaultClient
public static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
            WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]);
    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

    if (result == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

I have placed my ClientId, ClientSecret, and SecretUri into my web app's Application Settings, just like the screenshot shows in the instructions. Since I did this, I can expect (from the instructions):

> If you have an Azure Web App, you can now add the actual values for the AppSettings in the Azure portal. By doing this, the actual values will not be in the web.config but protected via the Portal where you have separate access control capabilities. **These values will be substituted for the values that you entered in your web.config. Make sure that the names are the same.**

However, when I run the method above, the value for `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"]` resolves to `clientid` which is the dummy value, and likewise for ClientSecret. My understanding is that the method is supposed to reach out to the web app in the Azure Portal and substitute the values. **What am I missing? Why aren't the values being substituted?**

---

**Edit:** Also, it may be important that I'm using Azure Active Directory B2C instead of Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run or debug application from your local environment the application picks values from web.config and so you are seeing dummy values on your web page. Your application will pick values from Azure App settings when you deploy your application to Azure. Also, you need to keep Key Name same in web.config as well as in the Azure app setting. Hope this helps.